# A resilient clien-server logging famework

Tags: .net, logging

We have multiple WPF, Silverlight and web applications most of which go through our services layer. Due to the nature of the application, auditing access and changes is very important. Each error also needs to be logged. How do we go about ensuring that errors on clients propagate to the server once the client/server comes up again.

Initial thoughts are:

- Create windows service on the thick clients. These log all errors.
- The service at the client writes these onto a msmq queue or a document database.
- We periodically push the logs from the client to a logging service on the server.

I'm certain that someone out there would have already done this and am looking to pointers on what not to do and the lessons learned?

BTW, we are on .Net 4.0, all boxes are Windows and we will have AD in most deployments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the Syslog daemon from Kiwi.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ELMAH to log exceptions for web apps http://code.google.com/p/elmah/